# Problema para capturar datos de tabla html y enviar a combo box

Tags: jquery

**Estimados**

Estoy intentando capturar un dato de una tabla html y enviarlo a un combo box, pero no me funciona, solo me funciona si lo envío a un campo input.
he probado enviando el valor a la etiqueta  del combo pero no muestra nada.
aca les dejo un ejemplo que hice para poder explicar mi problema.

acá imagen de como funciona con input text.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá dejo el código.

```
<!DocType:html>

<html>

<head>

<title></title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/fechaHora.js"></script>-->

</head>

<body>

<h1>Formulario 1 capturar celda de tabla y mostrar en input text</h1>

<table border=1 cellpadding=0 id="tablatest">
<thead>

<tr>

<th>ID</th>

<th>NOMBRE</th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr>

<td>7889</td>

<td>HOLA</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>7676</td>

<td>HOLA2</td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

<br>

<form>

<div><b>Combo:</b></div>

<div class="col-sm-2"><select id="combo" class="form-control">

<option ></option>

</select>

</div>

</form>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#tablatest tbody tr ").on ("click",function (event) {

var id2= $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html();

$("#combo").val(id2);

});

});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Acá imagen del problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También probé pasando el valor por el id directo a la etiqueta  pero tampoco me funciona.
Como se podría pasar el valor al combo box?

Comment: Para poder poner el valor que quieres tiene que existir una `option` con el `value` que quieres poner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar una nueva opción con `append`, te muestro el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
$("#tablatest tbody tr ").on("click",function (event) {

var id2= $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html();

//Colocar false en vez de true si no deseas que se muestre como opción seleccionada en el combo
$("#combo").append(new Option(id2, "value", false, true));

//Remover esta línea si deseas que se repitan las opciones
$(this).off('click');     

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h1>Formulario 1 capturar celda de tabla y mostrar en input text</h1>

<table border=1 cellpadding=0 id="tablatest">
<thead>

<tr>

<th>ID</th>

<th>NOMBRE</th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr>

<td>7889</td>

<td>HOLA</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>7676</td>

<td>HOLA2</td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

<br>

<form>

<div><b>Combo:</b></div>

<div class="col-sm-2"><select id="combo" class="form-control">

</select>

</div>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Lo que realicé para que no se repitieran las opciones fue remover el evento, de tal modo que ya no se agregará la opción al combo al hacer `click`.

Te comparto la documentación del `append` por si lo necesitas: [Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

También te comparto la documentación donde se especifica el funcionamiento del `new Option`: [Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Si sirve, el único problema es que a medida que se hace click, los valores se van duplicando en el combo y estos no se ven selecionados, sino que hay que ver el combo y ahi seleccionarlos

Comment: @SimónPereiraVigouroux listo compañero, por un momento no me di cuenta que eras el OP, ya modifiqué la respuesta a como solicitaste en los comentarios, ten en cuenta que esos detalles debes especificarlos en la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Mil gracias me sirvió